# How to change Minecraft screenshots folder?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How can I change where screenshots taken in Minecraft (using F2) get saved?

By default they are saved to the Minecraft game directory's "screenshots" subdirectory, e.g. `%APPDATA%\.minecraft\screenshots`, and I haven't found any way at all, via the game's menus or the game's configuration files, to change it.

I would like to save screenshots to my Desktop.

Comment: Why did you answer your own question? If you already knew the answer, then don't ask it.

Comment: @TimMcCool [it's standard and respectable practise on StackExchange](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer#:~:text=To%20encourage%20people%20to%20do,of%20the%20Ask%20Question%20page.), the point is to [make StackExchange a store of good questions and answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17851/276692) so that eventually any question you would want to ask has already been answered here. I tried to find an answer to this question many times over the last months. Finally figured out how to do it myself. Would have been great if this exact post had been a top google hit.

Answer (score 11):

Minecraft does not provide any support for changing the screenshot folder.

However, you can make a symlink using your Operating System.

If you replace Minecraft's screenshots folder with a new folder, still called "screenshots", that actually links to another location, then Minecraft will unwittingly start saving screenshots in the location you want.

So first, delete the original Minecraft directory screenshots folder (or you can rename it, if you want to save all the screenshots already inside of it without moving them to somewhere else). Then, do one of the following depending on your operating system:

In Windows, you can run this command in cmd.exe (in some versions of Windows you may have to 'Run as administrator'):

```
mklink /d %APPDATA%\.minecraft\screenshots %UserProfile%\Desktop
```

On macOS, this is the command:

```
ln -s ~/Desktop ~/Library/Application\ Support/minecraft/screenshots
```

Linux is the same as macOS, except the location of the minecraft game directory is different:

```
ln -s ~/Desktop ~/.minecraft/screenshots
```

These commands make a new symlink in your Minecraft directory called "screenshots".

After setting up a symlink in your Minecraft directory for screenshots, all new screenshots will be saved to the location that the link points to!